# Upload image to server from android Api 23 and above

Tags: android, file-upload

I wanted my app to pick a image from the gallery of Android and Upload it on the server. And the code works great on API lenel 22 i.e lollipop. But *fails with an NullPointerException on API Level 23*. Is there any change after API 23? If so what is it.

Here is the code I used.

```
 public void onClickAddProfileImage(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PROFILE_PHOTO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_PROFILE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            uploader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, selectedImage, projection, null, null, null);
            Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(column_index));
            cursor.close();
            Intent in = new Intent();
            UploadFile file_upload = new UploadFile(this, in);
            file_upload.execute();
        }
    }
```

And the **error** log I got on line

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(column_index));
```

is

```
     Process: com.webkul.taskapp, PID: 2648  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:205520 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.webkul.taskapp/com.webkul.taskapp.BaseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3720)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3763)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:475)
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java)
        at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:437)
        at com.webkul.taskapp.BaseActivity.onActivityResult(BaseActivity.java:535)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6442)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3716)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3763) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)     
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Please anyone give any suggestions to resolve it.

Comment: So cursor==null. Or cursor.getString() ==null. If you check that before use you will not have that exception.

Comment: What is the type of `selectedImage` ?

Comment: `Uri imageUri`. You are not using `imageUri`.

Comment: @greenapps cursor.getString(column_index) is null and i am getting column_insex=0 everytime.

Comment: Maybe its something with the permissions. Did you ask the user for the permission to access files? Well, in 23+ apis you need to ask for the permission, then only you can access the files.

Comment: @KarunShrestha its not permission error as I already had implemented runtime permissions and I am able to go to Gallery and choose a Picture. Also I am getting response in `data.getData()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a lot of code you are trying to construct an Uri from ... an Uri.

`data.geData()` is the Uri already  which you can use to open an `InputStream` for uploading the file.

Comment: No I am unable to use the Uri i got with `data.getData()` with FileInputStream even in lollipop version.
`fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedImage.getPath());`
Its giving FileNotFoundException.

Comment: You should not use a FileInputStream; I said `InputStream`.  Change to `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());`.

Comment: can you please share a blog link , gist or any example regarding the same.

Comment: Why.? What problems do you have? Put that statement for a test directly in onActivityResult() (as first statement) and report if its opens the stream without exceptions. For the rest your upload code is exactly the same. Just change FileInputStream to InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue but resolved it by using this third party library
https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun